# Direct I/O possible with Cray compiler?

Tags: io, compilation, cray

I am trying to compile a C code that uses direct I/O.  There is one line that uses the O_DIRECT flag:

```
fd = open(fileName,O_DIRECT | O_RDWR | O_CREAT,0600)
```

Intel and GNU understand this just fine and compile.  Cray cannot get past O_DIRECT.  It does not think it is set anywhere.  Does the Cray compiler have some alternative for this variable?  Or can it just not do direct I/O?

Answer (score 0):

Give the compiler command the `-D'_GNU_SOURCE'` flag.  It will allow it to pick some things, mainly `O_DIRECT`, in the header file `/usr/include/bits/fcntl-linux.h` that it won't pick up otherwise.